# I have a question regarding wp_dequeue_script

Tags: wordpress

I would like to block to load comment-reply.js file on pages.

Theme functions.php,

```
function theme_enqueue_scripts() {
if (is_singular() && get_option('thread_comments'))  
wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply'); }
```

So, I added codes to block that js file in child theme's functions.php,

```
function comment_load_script() {
if ( is_single()) {return;}
wp_dequeue_script('comment-reply');}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'comment_load_script' );
```

However, comment-reply.js is still loaded on every page. I need your help. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. Its working fine.

```
function comment_load_script(){
    wp_deregister_script( 'comment-reply' ); 
} 
add_action('init','comment_load_script');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I've solved this problem by adding 99;add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'comment_load_script', 99 ); Which is better do you think for better performance? :)

Comment: Glad to help you :). Accept the answer if its works.

Comment: I used this code, and it works. What's the difference between dequeue and deregister?
function comment_load_script() {
if ( is_single()) {return;}
wp_dequeue_script('comment-reply');}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'comment_load_script', 99);

Comment: `To be dequeued, the script must have been enqueued. Attempting to dequeue a script before the script is enqueued will have no effect.`

Comment: Please read this https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script

Comment: I see, so 99 has effect after ordering the scripts. Thank you so much! :)