# Javascript library lightbox2 in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, lightbox, elementor, lightbox2

I have 2 galleries in wordpress, elementor. I want to merge them into one. Don't ask why :)
I'm using this js, it works perfectly, but only if I'm logged in wp. But when I log out, the js doesn't work and the lightbox takes over the original lightbox from elementor.

Does anyone know what to do about this please?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.3/css/lightbox.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.3/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
<script>
    
const galleryLinks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.elementor-image-gallery a[data-elementor-open-lightbox="yes"]'));


galleryLinks.forEach(link => {
  console.log(link.href);
  link.setAttribute('data-lightbox', 'gallery'); // Přidání atributu pro Lightbox galerii
});

lightbox.option({
  'resizeDuration': 200,
  'wrapAround': true,
  'showImageNumberLabel': false
});
    
</script>
```

[logged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYyZp.png)
[not logged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49l73.png)

I've tried everything...

Comment: Probably is priority issue. I would use wp_dequeue_script and remove the original ones.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't really understand this function. Could you show me an example?

Comment: this example is deregistering script - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57231272/i-have-a-question-regarding-wp-dequeue-script but the logic is the same. And examples with wp_dequeue_script  -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507179/wp-dequeue-script-for-child-theme-to-replace-script